# Swift3 JSON using Alamofire

Tags: json, swift3, alamofire

I'm new to Alamofire and Swift.

Now, I'm trying to convert JSON from the API, but I don't know how to convert it.

API like this :

```
[
{    
  "myid": "10303210302003",    
  "mySubid": "10303210302003",    
  "area_pkid": "3"    
},

{      
  "myid": "10303210302004",   
  "mySubid": "10303210302004",    
  "area_pkid": "4"    
}, 
....]
```

I'm so confused about "[" and "]" , I don't know how to convert it and get myid.

Here is my code

```
    Alamofire.request(MyURL, method: .get).responseJSON { (response) in

       guard let totalJSON = response.result.value as? [String : Any] else { return } // My code is just return !! WHY??

    }
```

Comment: Very easy: `[]` is array, `{}` is dictionary. Hint: the root object is not a dictionary.

Comment: @vadian Thank you !!!! Awesome , I 'll keep trying

Comment: @vadian Thank u , I got it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply

```
guard let totalJSON = response.result.value as? [[String : Any]] else { return }
for item in totalJSON {
   print(item["myid"] as? String ?? "n/a")
}
```

since the enclosing object is an array (`[]`)

You can even cast the array to `[[String:String]]` if all values are `String`

Comment: Than you again my friend !!  :)

Answer (score 1):

Yep, `[]` is an array and `{}` represents as Dictionary. So to get `myid` just do:

```
   guard let totalJSON = response.result.value as? [Any] else { return }
   if let i = a["myID"] as? String, let a = totalJSON[0] as? [String: Any] 
   {
      print(i)
   }
```

Comment: Than you!! I got it :)